# unity how to make scroll view children scale to fit screen on mobile?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas, scrollviewer

they say a picture is worth a thousand words so please check the image attached, right now my scroll view doesnt fill the screen on mobile devices, it does fill the screen in the editor, each child added is anchored to the top left and falls just short of filling the screen ive used every component i should be, canvas scaler, layout elements etc, but i cant get it to (match parent) fill the screen on mobile devices! [image]any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow tutorial : [Scroll View](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/scroll-view).

Few other things that you can try:

1. Use View Port.
2. Select Child Force Expand options in Vertical Layout group.
3. In Game View choose phone's resolution/display instead of "Free Aspect" to see how it would look in phone.

Besides, "Header" is only child in layout group, which is already visible. try adding more items to see if scroll rect is are expanding.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: i add more programmatically i aput that one in for show, that tutorial is the one ive followed, im aware of changing the aspect in the editor but thanks for reminding me, and i have looked at changing the child force expand but dont know fully what they do could you elaborate at all

Comment: Force expand on x and then set height using layout element. Also add content size fitter to the element which you want to scale.(layout element goes with content size fitter).